# How do you send a curl request to a specific edge node?

Tags: curl, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to send a curl request to a specific amazon edge node from the list that is published on their website: https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json.
Any time I try this I receive either no response from webpage or a jumble of character in the terminal. I am new to curl so I might just be doing it incorrectly.
Is this possible or must all the web request be sent directly to amazon?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Why do you wish to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you pin an ip address to your curl request?
Example shown below:

```sh
curl http://www.example.com --resolve www.example.com:80:127.0.0.1
```